# How do I calculate the annihilator of series with fraction?

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

How do I calculate the annihilator of this:
$$s_n = s_{n-1} + \frac{1}{(n + 1)(n + 2)(n + 3)}$$

I know that $E-1$ is the annihilator part for $s_n - s_{n-1}$ but I don't know how to get the part for the fraction.

I need to find the closed form of $s_n$ and the first thought I had was to use annihilators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what an annialtor is but if you want a closed form of $s_n$ you can telescope as follows:

$$\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}=\frac{1}{n+1} \left( \frac{1}{n+2} - \frac{1}{n+3} \right) = \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)} - \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+3)}\\
=\frac{1}{n+1} - \frac{1}{n+2} - \frac 12\left( \frac{1}{n+1} - \frac{1}{n+3}\right)\\
=\frac12 \left(\frac{1}{n+1} - \frac{2}{n+2} + \frac{1}{n+3}\right).
$$

Can you start from here?

Comment: That's great, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

$$s_n-s_{n-1}=\frac{1}{(n+1) (n+2) (n+3)}\tag{1}$$
The homogeneous recurrence
$$s_n-s_{n-1}=0$$
has the trivial solution $s_n=s_0$

To solve $(1)$ we guess the particular solution to be
$$s_n^*=\frac{a}{n+2}+\frac{b}{n+3}$$
plug this in the recurrence and get
$$\frac{a}{n+2}+\frac{b}{n+3}-\frac{a}{n+1}-\frac{b}{n+2}=\frac{1}{(n+1) (n+2) (n+3)}$$
and then
$$\frac{n (-a-b)+(-3 a-b)}{(n+1) (n+2) (n+3)}=\frac{1}{(n+1) (n+2) (n+3)}$$
so we have to solve the system
$$\begin{cases}
-a-b=0\\
-3a-b=1\\
\end{cases}\to a=-\frac{1}{2};\;b=\frac12
$$
The particular solution is
$$s_n^*=-\frac{1}{2(n+2)}+\frac{1}{2(n+3)}=-\frac{1}{2 (n+2) (n+3)}$$
and
$$s_n=s_0+s_n^*\to s_n=s_0-\frac{1}{2 (n+2) (n+3)}$$
for $n=0$ we have $s_0=\frac{1}{12}$
Finally the solution of the recurrence is
$$s_n=s_0+\frac{1}{12}-\frac{1}{2 (n+2) (n+3)}\to s_n=s_0+\frac{n (n+5)}{12 (n+2) (n+3)}$$

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Why does $s_n - s_{n-1} = 0$ have trival solution $s_n = s_0$? And also how did you guess $s_n^*$?

Comment: $s_n=s_{n-1}$ the sequence is constant. The guess is done looking the RHS

Comment: Thank you very much!